Studying the sequence: $a_n$ is the smallest positive real number s.t. $\vert a_i-a_n\vert\geq\frac{1}{n}\ \forall\ i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,n-1\}.$

Let $a_0=0.$ For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $a_n$ be the smallest
positive real number such that
$$\vert a_i-a_n\vert\geq\frac{1}{n}\quad\forall\
 i\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,n-1\}. $$
Is $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ bounded?

The sequence starts $0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{7}{10}, \frac{7}{6}, \frac{59}{70}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{13}{36}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{12}{11}, \frac{155}{132},\ldots.$
Has anyone studied this sequence before? (I couldn't find it anywhere...).
It seems to me  this sequence is somewhat chaotic and therefore my question might be difficult.
I also don't see how to use the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges: in fact, this seems irrelevant.

Can show that $a_{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^k}$. $\quad$ I suspect (without proof) that $a_{3\times2^k} = 1 + \frac{1}{3\times 2^k}$.

Did you mean to include 0 in the set of possibilities for $i$?

@Nic well spotted! I amended the question.

@AdamRubinson $a_{11} \neq \frac{ 12}{11}$ since $ a_6 - \frac{12}{11} = \frac{7}{6}  - \frac{12}{11} = \frac{5}{66}  < \frac{1}{11}$. I believe that $a_{11} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{11}$ and $a_{12} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{12} $ (per my comment).

I will show that the sequence is bounded above by 2.
I believe (no proof) that the least upper bound is $ \leq \frac{3}{2}$.
I propose an alternative way to define $a_n$:

Given $a_0, a_1, \ldots a_{n-1}$, find the minimum value of $a_i$ that satisfies $$(\min_{a_j > a_i} a_j) - a_i \geq 2/n.$$
Let this value be denoted as $a_{I_n}$.
Then define $b_n = a_{I_n} + \frac{1}{n}$.

From my definition, since $|a_i - b_n| \geq \frac{1}{n}$ by construction, hence  $b_n \geq a_n$. So an upper bound on $b_n$ gives us an upper bound on $a_n$.
(In fact, we have $b_n = a_n$ hence this is truly an alternative definition, but that is not required and left to the reader.)
Now, consider the intervals of the form $[a_i, a_i + \frac{2}{n})$ where $ a_i < a_{I_n}$. There are at most $n-1$ of them.
By construction, the union of these intervals is an interval (Why?) that contains $0$ and $a_{I_n}$ (Why?).
They have a total length of at most $2 - \frac{2}{n}$, hence the union is contained within $[0, 2 - \frac{2}{n})$.
So $a_{I_n} < 2 - \frac{2}{n} $ and $a_n < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$, and so $a_n$ is bounded above by 2.

Notes:

As I mentioned in the comments, we can show that $a_{2^k} = \frac{1}{ 2^k}$ (use the above definition for a quick proof).
For $n \neq 2^k$, let $k_n = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor $, and there are overlaps in the intervals $(a_0, a_0 + \frac{2}{n} )$, $(\frac{1}{2^{k_n}}, \frac{1}{2^{k_n}} + \frac{2}{n} )$, $(\frac{1}{2^{k_n - 1}}, \frac{1}{2^{k_n-1}} + \frac{2}{n} )$. By removing these overlaps, $a_{I_n} \leq 2 - \frac{2}{n} - (\frac{4}{n} - \frac{2}{2^{k_n} })$ gives a slight improvement to the constraint, but not to the upper bound.
It follows that $a_n =  \frac{1}{n} +  \sum_{j \in J_n} \frac{1}{j}$, where $J_n \subset [n-1]$.

We can represent this as a rooted tree with leaves of height $\frac{1}{i}$, but I wasn't able to make much progress with that interpretation. It seems surprising that this tree is bounded above, so it must be very flat and bushy.
(If my calculations are correct) The tallest branch arises from $ \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{43} + \ldots $, where I conjecture that the denominator follows $ c_n = 4 c_{n-1}  - 1 $, which could then lead to $a_n < \frac{3}{2}$.



